# Android - testing vs. production version

Tags: android, build

I am facing problem. I need to build one app in two ways, first build is for development (testing) use, second build should be production version. Are there any ways how to do it programatically? (with some build engines) I mean that both apps shloud run on one device at the same time if possible. Both version are APK from one Android project.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Personally I use this to determine whether I am in debugging mode:

```
final PackageInfo pinfo = getPackageInfo(ctx);
final boolean debugMode = (pinfo.applicationInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_DEBUGGABLE) != 0;
```

This code is based on the `debuggable` attribute of the `Application` tag of the `android-manifest.xml`:

- If this attribute is explicitely set to `true` `debugMode` will be set to `true`.
- But if it is explicitely set to `false` or not present in the xml (implicit values), `debugMode` will be set to `false`.

Doing this way you cannot run both app on the same device at the same time as two APK need two different package name to be installed concurrently. So you have to build two eclipse projects, each one having its own package name (for example `com.example.myapp.debug` and `com.example.myapp`), and why not using a common lib (`com.example.myapp.common`) that would contain almost all your code:

- `com.example.myapp.debug` has its `debuggable` flag set to `true`
- and `com.example.myapp` has its `debuggable` flag set to `false`

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I am looking now for some soplutions based on build.xml code, I want to build both developer version and release (stable) version, while debugging my application. Both versions could be able to run separately on one Android phone in one time (so no overrite, when installing).

Comment: I see. Isn't the second part satisfactory to do that?

Comment: Thanks for that first code snippet there!  I was about to ask if there was a way I could change resources based on whether I was using a debug or release APK, so that should work for me.

Comment: The second part of the solution is terrible... mantain 2 separate projects for debug and release versions... no no. and what if you need staging version for example, then you have 3 projects?

Comment: Depends of what you are willing to do, as explained in the post. Remember that different projects can share the same code base.

Comment: Just in case someone needs to do this same thing outside an Activity or in a single line: 

`boolean debuggable = (0 != (context.getApplicationInfo().flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_DEBUGGABLE));`

Answer (score 1):

As far as I see, you really need to create different applications from you base code. One way to get this done, as I did it, is to use Ant script that copies the entire project source into another directory, say "testing", and while doing so, replaces (e.g. using copy filtering) certain values from XML files, like from AndroidManifest.xml. One of the first things to replace is applications package that needs to be unique for each app. The Java classes like Activities can still reside in the original packages, their names in AndroidManifest.xml just need to be absolute. Once source has been copied and filtered, you can use Ant's antcall task from the main build.xml to build the customized app. So at the end, you can say e.g.: "ant -Denv=testing build" and you have an APK that can be installed next to your production version.

Another alternative is to use Maven that's Android plugins support project overlaying. And of course you can use library projects, see: [Android – multiple custom versions of the same app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1222302/android-multiple-custom-versions-of-the-same-app).

Comment: Thanks, I have started working with Ant now, but how to replace part of a strings with different parts?

Comment: To replace content in text files, see Ant's filtersets: http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/filterset.html. To manipulate existing XML file, you can use xmltask from: http://www.oopsconsultancy.com/software/xmltask/.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the easiest solution is to use some kind of source control tool for this purpose. There are so many good reasons to use source control, that I believe that most developers already use it.

Summery of solution:

1. Have 2 repositories (or branches), one for development and one for production.
2. Choose different package name for production and development apps.
3. Use absolute path for activities rather than relative in manifest file.
4. Solve the conflict only in the first time that you pull the changes from the development to the production environment.

Description of solution.

I personally works with GIT, I believe that this approach will work with other SCM tools, but I didn't test it.

1. I have 2 repositories, one for development and one for production (You can get the same effect using production branch, but I preferred different repositories, since I never know when I'll have another developers, and I don't want to give anyone (including me) the chance to do a mistake with the code without having a backup for it.
2. All you need to do is to set different package name in the manifest file in each repository, for example:
3. Development manifest package name - dev.com.foo.appName
4. Production manifest package name - com.foo.appName
5. For each activity there is a need to use the absolute path rather than the relative approach. Since there is no real option that you will change your package name, and if you do, all the changes are in the manifest file, I don't think that there is almost any drawbacks with this approach.
6. Then every time that you pull your changes from the developer repository to the production one, there should be a "conflict" on those lines in the manifest files, but actually there will be a conflict only on the first time you pull the code, afterwards the merging tools knows which line you prefer in the production repository.

### EDIT

After using this approach for some time I discovered that there is a problem with the generated R file.

**The problem:**
R file is being generated with package name as defined in the Manifest file in the package attribute. Then all references to R file cannot be find (The package name of the source files is differed from the package name stated in the manifest file).

There are 3 solutions for that problem:

**The Good:**
This solution is the most robust one, and I suggest you to use it (didn't try it myself though). The idea behind this solution is to generate the R file into a different class name than the one stated in the manifest. In the manifest the package would be dev.com.foo.appName but the R file will be generated to the com.foo.appName.
In order to achieve it please follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4313271/change-r-class-package-android-eclipse)

**The Bad:**
Do NOT use this solution, it is really bad, I'm stating it here that you could avoid it. In each file that using the R file add the import to the R file with the package name is in the manifest. This is a very bad solution, since you will enter a lot of unrelated code, you will need to change it in the production environment, and for every new class you will need to remember to add it.

**And the Ugly:**
It is better not to use this solution since it is a kind of a hack. This solution is useful only for mature apps that don't have lots of changes in their resources. When ever you change your resources the R file is being generated again, then it is generated to the package name as in the manifest. All you need to do is to change the package name (in the manifest) to be as in the production environment, clean the project, build it again, and change back the package name into the development environment. Then eclipse asks if to change configuration and you choose not to. This way, 2 R files will be exist, one with the development package name and one with the production one. Since in mature apps there are not much resources changes, you will be doing so once in a while. You won't be able to forget about it, since in case that you change a resource you will start seeing weird bugs.

Answer (score 0):

*I know question is late, but I will answer.*

You may use **Gradle**.

In *build.gradle* file you may define separate `buildTypes` like this:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
      runProguard false
      proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'      
    }   

    test {
      applicationIdSuffix ".test"
      versionNameSuffix "t"
      debuggable false
    }
```

By set `applicationIdSuffix` for may install *test* and *release* build on one device

For more info go to http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide